# If the phone is sleeping, i.e black screen, how to awake it

Tags: android, android-activity

How can we check whether the phone is in idle mode. I have made a activity which user sensor data. I think sensor doesn't work when the phone is idle, keyguard screen (black screen). I could have used service instead of activity but what to do to make screen illuminated when a particular activity starts so that sensors starts listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers :(.
Overcome the problem using service. Guys don't use activities for getting sensor data instead use service. Please share if somebody knows a better answer.